# assigning value to arguments while recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a small doubt in this recursion
when `will` called in main for first time the value of p will be -1
say when first recursive call will be made to `dfs(2,3)`(let u=2,v=3)
then will 3  be converted to -1 automatically ? or `(2,3)` will be passed 
as it is and -1 will be for only first recursive call

```
void dfs(int v, int p = -1) {
    par[v] = p;
    for (int u : G[v]) {
        if (u == p) continue;

        f[u] += f[v];
        printf("%d",f[u]);
        dfs(u, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call `dfs` with two arguments, both will be set to `v` and `p` respectively. No default value if you pass two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void dfs(int v, int p = -1)`, `-1` is the default value.

so when you write

```
dfs(42);
```

it is in fact

```
dfs(42, -1);
```

but if you provide argument, default value is not used.